# TDD & Design Advice

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd

I have a method which calls an `Action<string>`

```
public Action<string> DisplayError;

public void MyMethod()
{
  DisplayError("ERROR");
}
```

In this method I want to call DisplayError however I can see that if DisplayError is null it will thrown an exception.

I can run a test that proves that it will throw an exception.

So I know I want to add a `if (DisplayError != null)` to my code but I feel this design is wrong somehow. Maybe the test should be different?

Comment: Whenever possible, avoid passing/returning null. In this case, you can default DisplayError to a No-Op Action that does nothing when it is called. It's a broken window like symptom, the first null-check causes null-checks to start mushrooming all over the place. A Null reference exception should mean that something is wrong and should be fixed ASAP either via design or improving awareness on how to use your library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making Action a public field, make it a property or pass it into the method. You can then do the null checking at that point. I also doubt that you need to retrieve it after setting it, so either:

```
_displayError = (s) => { throw new ArgumentNullException("Please tell me what to do with this exception!"); };

public Action<string> DisplayError
{
    set 
    {
        if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("I need this!"); }
        _displayError = value;
    }
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    _displayError("ERROR");
}
```

Or:

```
public void MyMethod(Action<string> displayError)
{
    if (displayError == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("I need this!"); }
    displayError("ERROR");
}
```

The first of these shouldn't require any code changes from your consumers.

Of course, if you're just working with a team who are using your code, you *shouldn't need to null-check at all*. Just find out who's using your code wrong and have a friendly chat to work out where the misunderstanding is. Defensive programming is not a good substitute for a team whose members trust each other, and null-checking is not as effective as having a clearly defined, easy-to-use interface.

You'll need 2 tests:

My class:

- should allow the consumer to handle any error

  - Given I'm going to produce an error for whatever reason (set context here)
  - When I produce an error (call the method, let the error handler set some variable)
  - Then I should give the error to the handler (check the variable that got set)
- should make sure an error handler is attached

  - Given I might produce an error (you can code what you like here because it's irrelevant)
  - When the consumer calls me without an error handler (call the method with a null error handler)
  - Then I should immediately ask the consumer not to do that (check for an exception)

Comment: I've gone with the latter option but am unsure what my tests should be showing

Comment: Updated. Name the tests after those "shoulds", put the "Given, When, Then" in comments, fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on context.

Is the user of this class *required* to set the value based on a contract?  Then it should throw an exception.

Is it optional?  Then your check is valid but if you just default `DisplayError` to an empty Action, you'll get similar behavior

```
DisplayError = s => {};
```

Your approach also leads to the possibility that the user can *set* `DisplayError` to `null` and in that case, only you can decide what's valid.  If you set that to a property instead of a field, you'll give yourself more options.

```
_displayError = s => {};

public Action<string> DisplayError
{
   get { return _displayError; }
   set 
   { 
       _displayError = value ?? (s => {}); 
       /* or throw on null */
   }
}
```

Comment: The class is going to have a Windows forms control in it and I thought I would assign a routine on the form (that updates the GUI) equal to this action. At the moment the form implementation does not exist and I'm just testing this method/action

Comment: @Jon, if you or your team-mates are responsible for the form that updates the GUI it's probably better to make sure that nobody calls the class with null than it is to put null-checks in it. Don't program stuff that won't be used in production - it just makes maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: @Jon:  Will your controls implement some required interface?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was in a talk from Steve Yeggie that I heard the point: something to the tune of 'while statically typed languages do protect you from a wide class of errors at compile-time, they do not negate the need for null-checking.'

I find this perfectly normal.

I'm just drinking my morning coffee, so let me know if I completely missed the mark.

Comment: I know I need to add the code to check for nulls but I think the test or something is not sitting right. Do I run a test that proves if I dont assign the action it throws a null or do I do a test that shows when it is assigned it executes?

Comment: I think it's justifiable to add a test if you think that the possibility of the action being null might be a problem. You'd be kicking yourself later if it passed until production and failed there because of it.